# AES Decryption in ruby and activerecord

Tags: ruby, activerecord, encryption

I have super ugly code that looks like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   self.table_name = 'users'
  def get_password
    @test_password = User.find_by_sql "SELECT CAST(AES_DECRYPT(Pass, 'kkk') AS CHAR(50)) Pass From prod.sys_users Where Owner = '"+@owner+"' AND User = '"+@user+"'"
    @test_password[0].Pass
  end
end
```

This code works, but it makes me sick, since it is not written according to Ruby Coding Style. So I decided to fix this code, and here what I have so far:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'users'
  def get_pass
    User.where(Owner: @owner, User: @user).pluck(:Pass).first
  end
end
```

So, I am getting encrypted password, how can I decrypt it?
I tired `OpenSSL`, but key `'kkk'` here is too short.
How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: An aside: For user passwords used for authentication to your own system, you would not normally use encryption but secure hashing. You *might* use encryption if the password was a secret used for access to some other external resource. It is not clear what your use case is here?

Comment: Thanks for response Neil, this class is used for automation purposes, I need password in order to log into web application

Comment: The `AES_DECRYPT(Pass, 'kkk')` is MySQL function documented here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt ? If so, the answer appears to be to add some padding up to block size.

Comment: I know, is there any ways to decrypt unencrypted data retrieved from pass column?

Comment: Yes I think there is, but it would take some experiments with correct padding and variant of AES to get it right. I don't have MySQL set up, so need to leave answer for someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a situation like this, you might be better off converting the field values entirely.  This could be done in a migration and once it's done, you never have to be concerned about how MySQL has stored the data.  It's also one step toward database independence.

So, the migration would basically do 3 things:

- add a flag column to track which records have been converted
- iterate over each records, converting the encrypted value and setting the flag
- remove the flag column once all records have been processed

The migration might look like this:

```
class ConvertMySqlEncryptedData < ActiveRecord::Migration
  # Local proxy class to prevent interaction issues with the real User class
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  end

  def up
    # Check to see if the flag has already been created (indicates that migration may have failed midway through)
    unless column_exists?(:users, :encrypted_field_converted)
      # Add the flag field to the table
      change_table :users do |t|
        t.boolean :encrypted_field_converted, null: false, default: false
      end
    end

    # Add an index to make the update step go much more quickly
    add_index :users, :encrypted_field_converted, unique: false

    # Make sure that ActiveRecord can see the new column
    User.reset_column_information

    # Setup for AES 256 bit cipher-block chaining symetric encryption
    alg = "AES-256-CBC"
    digest = Digest::SHA256.new
    digest.update("symetric key")
    key = digest.digest
    iv = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new(alg).random_iv
    key64 = Base64.encode(key)

    # Don't update timestamps
    ActiveRecord::Base.record_timestamps = false
    begin
      # Cycle through the users that haven't yet been updated
      User.where(encrypted_field_converted: false).pluck("CAST(AES_DECRYPT(Pass, 'kkk') AS CHAR(50)) Pass").each do |user|
        # Re-encode the password with OpenSSL AES, based on the setup above
        new_pass = aes.update(user.pass).final

        # Update the password on the row, and set the flag to indicate that conversion has occurred
        user.update_attributes(pass: new_pass, encrypted_field_converted: true)
      end
    ensure
      # Reset timestamp recording
      ActiveRecord::Base.record_timestamps = true
    end
  end

  def down
    # To undo or not undo, that is the question...
  end
end
```

This was off the top of my head, so there may be issues with the encryption.  Structure-wise, it should be in good shape, and it takes into account a number of things:

- Provides incremental database processing by using a flag to indicate progress
- Uses an index on the flag field to improve query performance, particularly if multiple runs are required to complete processing
- Avoids updating the `updated_at` column to prevent overwriting prior values that may be useful to keep (this is not a material change, so `updated_at` doesn't require updating)
- Plucks only the `pass` field, so that transfer overhead is minimized

Now, you can query `pass` and encrypt/decrypt as needed by the application.  You can document and support the field at the application level, rather than rely on the database implementation.

I spent a few years consulting and doing database conversion, either from one database product to another, or as part of a significant version upgrade.  It also allows development to use lighter-weight databases (e.g. SQLite) or test viability with other products when upscaling is needed.  Avoiding database-specific features, like the MySQL encryption, will save you (or your employer) a LOT of money and hassle in the long run.  Database independence is your friend; embrace it and use what ActiveRecord provides to you.

Comment: Thank you! Great answer!